# Url rewriting different name for file if empty

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have a rewrites in place to add an author name so:

```
example.com/author/first-name-last-name
```

Now when someone navigates to:

```
example.com/author
```

it shows all the authors, however I would like the URL to be

```
example.com/authors
```

With an 's' appended at the end.
How can I achieve this without redirecting to an actual page called authors.php?

My current rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ author.php?authorslug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: whats your current rewrite rule?

Comment: it is currently: RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ author.php?authorslug=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

# show all authors
RewriteRule ^authors/?$ /author.php [L]

# show a particular author
RewriteRule ^author/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ author.php?authorslug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule before the one you already have:

```
RewriteRule ^author/?$ /authors.php [L]
```

Comment: I don't actually have a authors.php file.

Comment: @abushahin Then what do you want to actually get served? This made it sound like you wanted `authors.php` to be served: "*How can I achieve this without redirecting to an actual page called authors.php?*"

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood. I want the same page author.php but with an s appended so that it looks like authors.

Comment: @abushahin Then what's the problem with just adding an "s" at the end of `^author` in your rule's pattern?

Comment: Because when there is a get parameter I want example.com/author/name if there isn't a get parameter then I'd like example.com/authors. Hope you know what I mean.